# No dual display obtion on my Ubuntu 22.04.4

Tags: dual-boot, 22.04, display, error-handling

I am using a Lenovo Thinkbook 16 G6 (2024 version) laptop. I tried to install Ubuntu 22.04.4 (dual boot with Win11), but when I needed to use dual display, I found out that my Ubuntu has no dual screen option in the Display setting. I checked the cable and it works with the Windows but not with Ubuntu. I tried different versions, including 20.04 beta and 20.04.6, and they also didn't work. The two latter versions had even more problems (no wifi and sound support). How can I fix this?

[image: you can look at this picture]

Comment: Your details are somewhat vague; you mention 20.04 *beta* so you have a *daily* from four years ago? as the *beta* release will show almost nothing as it's a *daily* of an *unreleased* product.  I'd look at what kernels are included; 20.04 is available with 2 kernel stacks where HWE has had 5 different kernels...  the HWE stack of 20.04 is the same kernel as available for 22.04 (its the GA stack for that release) but you don't specify kernel stack specifics (only release; probably desktop thus likely HWE only tested). What kernel modules (*drivers*) did you try? what video hardware do you have

Comment: You'll generally find newer hardware requires newer releases of Ubuntu; the newest you tried was the 2022-April release (likely with an updated kernel stack from 2023-Oct but you didn't specifically give ISO details)...  I'd have tried using Linux kernels 6.5 or newer (eg. 6.8 is available though off-topic here).